# Jersey: get null textbox input value

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jersey

I want to use jQuery's autocomplete to do the following: When the user is typing text in the textbox, he will see a list of possible words fetched from the server. My HTML code is a simple textbox:

```
<label for="customer-name">Enter customer names: </label>
<input type="text" id="customer-name" name="customer-name"/>
```

The JavaScript code to send and get data from server is implemented by jQuery UI's [autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) and jQuery AJAX function:

```
$(function() {
    $("#customer-name").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
        url: '../account/customer-view',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: request.term,
        success: function(data) {
            response($.map(data, function(item) {
            return item;
            }));
        }
        });
    }
    });    
});
```

My backend is using Java Jersey's web service. The method to handle the AJAX post is:

```
@Path("customer-view")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getCustomerInfo(@FormParam("customer-name") String partialName) {
    // ... code to use partialName
}
```

However when I launched my application and debugged it, I found that when I enter a letter in the textbox, for example, a "C" in the textbox, the variable `partialName` doesn't get the value "C" from the `@FormParam` injection and it is `null`. Normally I always get the form parameter value by using `@FormParam`. But in this case, the value is always null. How can I get the form value from ajax post? Is `@FormParam` the correct one to use? If not, what should I use in this case to get the textbox value?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. In the AJAX request, the data sent to the server should be encapsulated in an object as:

```
data: {nameString: request.term}
```

Then on server-side, use `nameString` as the parameter of the `@FormParam` annotation:

```
public Response getCustomerInfo(@FormParam("nameString") String partialName) {
}
```

I don't know why we can't use `name` attribute in `<input>` tag as the parameter of the `@FormParam` in this case.